# Changing icons in Moderncv{Casual} Coverletter template

Tags: moderncv, cv

I am using the `Modercv{Casual}` template for my cover letter but want to change the icons of mobile phone, email, web address, github and linkedIn in my footer to the "Font Awesome" type to make it more compatible to my Resume header. I seem to find it hard that it is not accepting the Fa command after I have added the `fontawesome` package as it says to put in after the `\begin{document}` command. If I put it in the begin command the placement is not right as it obviously goes to the top of the document.

[image: When I add the Font Awesome command it puts it in top of the document]

[image: Want to change this footer icon to font awesome]

```
%% start of file `template.tex'. %% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com). % % This work may be distributed and/or modified under the % conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c, % available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman, colorlinks, linkcolor= cyan]{moderncv} 
%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes 
\moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking' 
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black' 
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using 
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt} %Horizontal distance between links to linkedin, website, email and phone number

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% adjust the page margins 
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data 
\name{JOSEPH,}{FERNANDO}

\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted 
%\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty

\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted 
\faMobile\enspace+3~(456)~789~012    
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted 
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}            % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted 
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file 
%\quote{Some quote}                                % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %            content
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
\begin{document}


\hypersetup{urlcolor= blue} % Adds blue color to the links 
%-----      letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data 
\recipient{ABB}{1250 Brown Rd\\Auburn Hills\\Michigan 48326} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Mr. ,} 
\closing{Yours sincerely,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\faLinkedin\enspace\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/jOSEPH/}{JOSEPH}
\makelettertitle

Opening Paragraph: What is your intent in writing this letter? What
position are you applying for and how did you learn about it? Briefly
introduce yourself, your major, and the degree anticipated. If you are
aware of a specific opening, refer to it. If you are not aware of a
specific position, state your area of interest. This  paragraph can
also be used to refer to the individual who  recommended that you
contact the organization, or other factors that prompted you to write.
If possible, convey why you are  interested in the organization and
anything you know about their product or service.

Second Paragraph: What are your qualifications? Why do you want to
work for this organization? What would you enjoy doing for them? Sell
yourself and be brief. Whet the employer’s appetite so that he/she
will want to read your resume and schedule an interview. Describe
highlights from your background that would be of greatest interest to
the organization. Focus on skills, activities, accomplishments, and
past experience you can contribute to the organization and its work.
If possible, demonstrate that you know something about the
organization and industry/field. Use action verbs that describe
relevant skills and expertise you can contribute. Mention specific
knowledge you may have such as computer applications, foreign
languages, lab techniques, writing and editing capabilities. You are
attempting to create a match or “notion of fit” between the employer’s
hiring needs and your  interests, experience, and skills

Third Paragraph: What is your plan of action? Do you want to follow up
with a phone call or do you want them to contact you? Close your
letter by stating that you would like to discuss employment
opportunities or other information with the individual and that you
will call to follow up on your letter. This demonstrates your
initiative and follow-through and will help you maintain some control
of your efforts.

Other points that can be made in the last paragraph: • Express your
willingness to provide additional information • State a specific time
when you will follow up by phone or email • Let them know if and when
you are going to visit their area • Thank the person receiving your
letter for their time and interest Most importantly, remember to
address the cover letter to a person. If you do not have a name, call
the department or human resources to find out to whom your letter
should be addressed. As a last resort, address your letter to the
personnel manager, hiring manager, or recruiting representative.

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Comment: One of the errors I recieve when i replace \phone command with \faMobile  is : "No begin document command was found "

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Done @BambOo, thanks I am posting a question for the 1st time so I am still learning how to format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your code are several issues:

1. There are special commands to add an mobile `\phone[mobile]{+3~(456)~789~012}` or linkedin `\social[linkedin]{john.doe}` informations to your CV/cover letter. Please see the changed MWE below.
2. With the additional information for the footer (personal informations) see warning after compiling and change the `\footskip` to the needed value with:

   ```
   \setlength{\footskip}{66pt}
   ```
3. Usuallly there is no comma after the first name. So I suggest to change `\name{JOSEPH,}{FERNANDO}` to `\name{JOSEPH}{FERNANDO}` ... rethink if you really need the chapital letters for the name ...
4. For me it seems you are using an old, outdated version of that cover letter. Therefore there are the new commands like `\social` missing. Please update to the current version 2.0.0 of `moderncv` to be able to compile the following MWE. Otherwise you will get error messages about undefined command `\social` etc.

With an current MiKTeX 2.9 and an current `moderncv`, version 2.0.0 I can compile the following MWE based on your code (please see important code changings marked with `<====`):

```
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com). 
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman, colorlinks, linkcolor=cyan]{moderncv} %\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

% moderncv themes 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt} %Horizontal distance between links to linkedin, website, email and phone number

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

% personal data 
\name{JOSEPH,}{FERNANDO}

\title{Resumé title}

\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[mobile]{+3~(456)~789~012} % <====================================
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} % <========== \faLinkedin\enspace\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/jOSEPH/}{JOSEPH}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt} % <=========================================


\begin{document}

\hypersetup{urlcolor= blue} % Adds blue color to the links 

\recipient{ABB}{1250 Brown Rd\\Auburn Hills\\Michigan 48326} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Mr. ,} 
\closing{Yours sincerely,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}

\makelettertitle

Opening Paragraph: What is your intent in writing this letter? What
position are you applying for and how did you learn about it? Briefly
introduce yourself, your major, and the degree anticipated. If you are
aware of a specific opening, refer to it. If you are not aware of a
specific position, state your area of interest. This  paragraph can
also be used to refer to the individual who  recommended that you
contact the organization, or other factors that prompted you to write.
If possible, convey why you are  interested in the organization and
anything you know about their product or service.

Second Paragraph: What are your qualifications? Why do you want to
work for this organization? What would you enjoy doing for them? Sell
yourself and be brief. Whet the employer’s appetite so that he/she
will want to read your resume and schedule an interview. Describe
highlights from your background that would be of greatest interest to
the organization. Focus on skills, activities, accomplishments, and
past experience you can contribute to the organization and its work.
If possible, demonstrate that you know something about the
organization and industry/field. Use action verbs that describe
relevant skills and expertise you can contribute. Mention specific
knowledge you may have such as computer applications, foreign
languages, lab techniques, writing and editing capabilities. You are
attempting to create a match or “notion of fit” between the employer’s
hiring needs and your  interests, experience, and skills

Third Paragraph: What is your plan of action? Do you want to follow up
with a phone call or do you want them to contact you? Close your
letter by stating that you would like to discuss employment
opportunities or other information with the individual and that you
will call to follow up on your letter. This demonstrates your
initiative and follow-through and will help you maintain some control
of your efforts.

Other points that can be made in the last paragraph: • Express your
willingness to provide additional information • State a specific time
when you will follow up by phone or email • Let them know if and when
you are going to visit their area • Thank the person receiving your
letter for their time and interest Most importantly, remember to
address the cover letter to a person. If you do not have a name, call
the department or human resources to find out to whom your letter
should be addressed. As a last resort, address your letter to the
personnel manager, hiring manager, or recruiting representative.

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

without errors and only three warnings (resulting from a known bug in `moderncv`) to the following cover letter:

[image: resulting letter]

Comment: Thank you so much !! I was indeed using an old modern cv template, finding the latest one helped in clearing my problem !!

Comment: @JapnitSethi You are welcome!